# NEED SOLUTION - Validation Error-Mempool-conflict

Tags: blockchain.info

I SENT XPUB and tried to send many messages blockchain never respond. and one account has been more than 5 days. 
i am having "validation Error-Mempool-conflict. what is this and how long it will take? Is this something blockchain stocks and steal our money? i have many accounts and two of my accounts got same issues since last week.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation Error: Error #-26: 258: txn-mempool-conflict](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58188/validation-error-error-26-258-txn-mempool-conflict)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Contact blockchain support.

Comment: I contacted blockchain support, they do nothing. it's been like 5 days and yesterday another account also has same issue. this is how they freeze our money? new account has over $19k and the old account which has issue has more than $250k

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution guys.

Possible fixes, broadcast your transaction on localbitcoin blockexplorer (yeah they have one) :
https://localbitcoinschain.com/tx/send

All fine with your coins the problem is in blockchain mempool and to unblock need to send transaction manually to bypass the blockchain mempool.

Solution step by step:

1. Open chrome inspector in the network tab
2. Try to create a transaction and get "Validation error"
3. Open "Headers" of pushtx request and copy content from FormData, field tx: "You need that content"
4. Enter that transaction in form here https://localbitcoinschain.com/tx/send and click submit
5. You'll get transaction id and can check it in blockexplorer this transaction belongs to you and you need to wait when it will be confirmed

Comment: When you have enough reputation you can comment on any post.